# Django - A model can't have more than one AutoField

Tags: python, django, models

This problem randomly started appearing for me.  I know that Django generates its own ids but a lot my code has been using custom AutoFields which HAS been working.  I added a new class today and tried to makemigrations but this error keeps showing up.

I DID remove all instances of AutoFields and retried migrating but the problem still persists which leads me to believe it's something else... I don't believe my Django version has changed at all...

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390,
 in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 441,
 in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrat
ions.py", line 98, in handle
    loader.project_state(),
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 326,
 in project_state
    return self.graph.make_state(nodes=nodes, at_end=at_end, real_apps=list(self
.unmigrated_apps))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 231,
in make_state
    project_state = self.nodes[node].mutate_state(project_state, preserve=False)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 8
3, in mutate_state
    operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, new_state)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py"
, line 51, in state_forwards
    state.reload_model(app_label, self.model_name_lower)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 152,
in reload_model
    self.apps.render_multiple(states_to_be_rendered)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 262,
in render_multiple
    model.render(self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 546,
in render
    body,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 189, in __
new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 324, in ad
d_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line
 989, in contribute_to_class
    "A model can't have more than one AutoField."
AssertionError: A model can't have more than one AutoField.
```

Here's an example of one of my fields:

```
assetid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

A lot of my code already depends on the name itself so changing it is going to be a big issue.  Furthermore, this was working perfectly before! I just can't seem to migrate it now.  I should mention im using a sqlite3 db.

Comment: You may want to add your migration file(s) to your question, and your new class (model?).

Comment: That solved it, deleting the newer migration files (somehow that screwed up the migration i believe) worked and i recommited it.  If you make a quick answer suggestion, ill mark it as answered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleted migration files and most recent history and fixed it.

Comment: How did you delete "most recent history"? with `migrate 0001` or `migrate 0001 --fake` before deleting the migration file?

Comment: @hobs I was having the same problem. I bet he did it manually: he opened my_app > migrations > pycache and deleted all .pyc files untracked by git (I bet he was using git and an editor like Atom or vs studio code), and my_app > migrations and deleted all the .py files untracked by git.

Comment: The better way is just unapply migrations(meaning run a previous migration).in this way the fields which sometimes are not removed from database are automatically removed from database.

Answer (score 10):

This is Because Django By default uses AutoField for the id.....so, if you want other fields to be AutoField, then make sure you confirm **primary_key=True**. 
Doing so deletes the id field from the Database.

I have used Mysql as my database. Be sure this problem might not solve in other databases.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem,

I commented out all the references to that model in all my app files, then run makemigrations and migrate, butit keeps telling that "A model can't have more than one AutoField." even if i am trying to deleting that file.

I had to reset my database.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I deleted id Autofield ,it works fine for me as Django uses Autofield by default

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

better way is just unapply migrations(meaning run a previous migration).in this way the fields which sometimes are not removed from database are automatically removed from database.Then, after changes you can easily do makemigrations again and then migrate and everything will be good.

Comment: _Please_ don't recommend deleting migrations! This is a great way to break your application.